# How does Linux treat (protected) memory region?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel

From dmesg, e820 logs:

```
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000180000000-0x000000047fffffff] (protected)
```

This identifies an NVDIMM type memory module.  But, how does linux (especially 4.2 up) treat this protected area? Does it use it as swap space, regular memory, or... ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be used by an Intel Persistent Memory (PMEM) driver introduced in Kernel version 4.1. The use is for persistent storage.

Persistent memory or storage is described at:

http://pmem.io/

This site explains PMEM as a sort of hybrid between Hard Disk/Solid State Disk persistent memory and volatile Random Access Memory (RAM).

From http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=PMEM-Linux-4.1-Feature&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Phoronix+%28Phoronix%29 :

"PMEM enables support for non-standard NVDIMMs and ADR protected memory. The new X86_PMEM_LEGACY Kconfig option explains, "Treat memory marked using the non-standard e820 type of 12 as used by the Intel Sandy Bridge-EP reference BIOS as protected memory. The kernel will offer these regions to the 'pmem' driver so they can be used for persistent storage.""

There are examples of people using it for the PMEM driver here:

https://lists.01.org/pipermail/linux-nvdimm/2015-February/000059.html

For a really in-depth article on Persistent Memory usage in Linux, see here:

http://lwn.net/Articles/640113/